# insertar datos de tipo time en sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql, tsql, time

Estoy haciendo un juego de datos para una aplicación, y al insertar un registro de tipo Time me da el siguiente error:

```
INSERT INTO [ope_prodqa_dev] 
   (
      staff, 
      turn, 
      date_prodqa,
      hour_dev
    ) 
   VALUES 
   (
      1,
      481,
      (SELECT CONVERT (datetime, '2016-10-23 20:44:11', 120)), 
      (SELECT CONVERT time,'12:05:06.0000000'))
    );
```

`hour_dev` es de tipo `TIME(7)` que se debe guardar con éste formato `07:45:00.0000000`
pero al hacer la INSERT me sale:

> `Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora.`

Answer (score 1):

Dado que se trata de una inserción, puedes usar simplemente `CAST` de este modo y sin tener que incurrir en ningún tipo de manejo de formatos, dejando que el sistema introduzca los valores con el mejor formato:

```
    INSERT INTO ope_prodqa_dev  
    (
      staff, 
      turn,
      date_prodqa, 
      hour_dev  
    ) 
   VALUES 
   (
      1,
      481,
      CAST ('2016-10-23 20:44:11' AS DATETIME), 
      CAST ('12:05:06.0000000' AS TIME)
    );
```

El resultado sería:

```
    staff   turn        date_prodqa                 hour_dev
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1       481         23.10.2016 20:44:11         12:05:06
```

Si estás en SQL Server 2012+, conviene usar `TRY_CAST` en lugar de `CAST`:

```
    INSERT INTO ope_prodqa_dev  
    (
      staff, 
      turn,
      date_prodqa, 
      hour_dev  
    ) 
   VALUES 
   (
      1,
      481,
      TRY_CAST ('2016-10-23 20:44:11' AS DATETIME), 
      TRY_CAST ('12:05:06.0000000' AS TIME)
    );
```

El resultado sería el mismo:

```
    staff   turn        date_prodqa                 hour_dev
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1       481         23.10.2016 20:44:11         12:05:06
```

Lo interesante es que `TRY_CAST` impedirá que la consulta falle en caso de haber un valor incorrecto. Insertando `NULL` en ese caso.

Supongamos esta consulta, donde, por error, se intenta pasar esta fecha: `XYZ2016-10-23 20:44:11`

Si usas solamente `CAST`, tendrías este error:

> `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.`

Pero si usas `TRY_CAST` la consulta funcionará, insertando `NULL` en la columna.

```
    INSERT INTO ope_prodqa_dev  
    (
      staff, 
      turn,
      date_prodqa, 
      hour_dev  
    ) 
   VALUES 
   (
      1,
      481,
      TRY_CAST ('XYZ2016-10-23a 20:44:11' AS DATETIME), 
      TRY_CAST ('12:05:06.0000000' AS TIME)
    );
```

El resultado sería:

```
    staff   turn        date_prodqa                 hour_dev
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1       481         NULL                        12:05:06
```

Si las columnas no soportan valores nulos, entonces puedes combinarlo con `ISNULL`, para que te introduzca `01.01.1900 00:00:00` en los valores fallidos.

Por ejemplo:

```
    INSERT INTO ope_prodqa_dev  
    (
      staff, 
      turn,
      date_prodqa, 
      hour_dev  
    ) 
   VALUES 
   (
      1,
      481,
      ISNULL(TRY_CAST ('XYZ2016-10-23 20:44:11' AS DATETIME),''),
      ISNULL(TRY_CAST ('120:05:06.0000000' AS TIME),'')
    );
```

El resultado sería:

```
    staff   turn        date_prodqa                 hour_dev
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1       481         01.01.1900 00:00:00         00:00:06
```

---

Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo con `CONVERT` :

```
INSERT INTO ope_prodqa_dev  
    (
      staff, 
      turn,
      date_prodqa, 
      hour_dev  
    ) 
VALUES 
   (
      1,
      481,
      CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-10-23 20:44:11',120), 
      CONVERT (TIME,'12:05:06.0000000')
    );
```

Si te interesa el manejo de nulos y no cuentas con SQL Server 2012+, puedes adaptar el código para que haga un correcto manejo de posibles valores erróneos. No insisto demasiado en ello porque no sé si te interesa, ni tampoco es el problema principal de la pregunta.

En cambio, si usas SQL Server 2012+ sería más interesante usar `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
    INSERT INTO ope_prodqa_dev  
    (
      staff, 
      turn,
      date_prodqa, 
      hour_dev  
    ) 
   VALUES 
   (
      1,
      481,
      ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-10-23 20:44:11',120),''), 
      ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT (TIME,'12:05:06.0000000'),'')
    );
```